# Using function to open and update values in external workbooks, but returning source errors

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

I've been using a function from another StackOverflow question (I'm SO sorry I can't find the original answer!) to help go through a number of cells in Column L that contains a formula that spits our a hyperlinked filepath. It is meant to open each one (workbook), update the values, then save and close the workbook before opening the next one. See below.

```
Sub List_UpdateAndSave()
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim WBSsource As Workbook
    Dim FileNames As Variant
    Dim msg As String
    ' Update the individual credit models
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List")
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
        FileNames = .Range("L2:L" & lr).Value
    End With
    For i = LBound(FileNames, 1) To UBound(FileNames, 1)
        On Error Resume Next
        If FileNames(i, 1) Like "*.xls*" Then
            Set WBSsource = Workbooks.Open(FileNames(i, 1), _
                                           ReadOnly:=False, _
                                           Password:="", _
                                           UpdateLinks:=3)
            If Err = 0 Then
                With WBSsource
                    'do stuff here
                    .Save
                    .Close True
                End With
            Else
                msg = msg & FileNames(i, 1) & Chr(10)
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
        End If

        Set WBSsource = Nothing
    Next i
    If Len(msg) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "The Following Files Could Not Be Opened" & _
               Chr(10) & msg, 48, "Error"
    End If
End Sub
```

The problem now is I am using this to work on a Network drive, and as a result it cause pathing issues with the Connections/Edit Links part. Each of the files are stored on `S:\...` which as a result of using the Hyperlink formula, won't be able to find the source data. See below the example image of a file that as been opened through a hyperlink cell from my original workbook. When I go to update the Edit Links section of it, it shows these errors. [image]

If I open that lettered drive in Windows Explorer and find the file, it works with no problems. Open, Update Values > Save > Close, it says unknown... [image]

(but if I click Update values here they update correctly.) [image]

If opened using a Hyperlink formula in a cell (Also directing to `S:\..`) it says it contains links that cannot be updated. I choose to edit links and they're all "Error: Source not found". The location on them also starts off with `\\\corp\...` and not `S:\`.

Anyway to fix this? Apologies for the long winded question.

Comment: It's not clear where the issue is - you talk about reading a range of hyperlinked filepaths, but you're reading the range's `Value`, so should we assume all paths are correctly represented in the cells' Text (ie. not the underlying hyperlink path)?  One suggestion would be to normalize all your paths: if the embedded links point to the UNC path then open your files from that path, instead of from your S drive.

Comment: Cells in K col are all text filepaths. Eg. K2 is "S:\Test Folder\Test File.xlsx". Cells in L column just Hyperlink that K col (ie. L2 is "=HYPERLINK(K2)".

Comment: I tried to change the embedded links to point to the UNC path and they open fine, but the Edit Links just can't seem to work with updating the UNC path?

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this as an answer as it contains code and is a bit long for a comment.
I'm not sure if it's what you're after though.

The code will take the mapped drive and return the network drive, or visa-versa for Excel files.  `DriveMap` is the variable containing the final string - you may want to adapt into a function.

```
Sub UpdatePath()

    Dim oFSO As Object
    Dim oDrv As Object
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim DriveMap As String

    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    FileName = Range("A1")

    If InStr(oFSO.GetExtensionName(FileName), "xls") > 0 Then

        For Each oDrv In oFSO.drives
            If oDrv.sharename <> "" Then
                'Changes \\corp\.... to S:\
                If InStr(FileName, oDrv.sharename) = 1 Then
                    DriveMap = Replace(FileName, oDrv.sharename, oDrv.Path)
                End If

                'Changes S:\ to \\corp\....
'                If InStr(FileName, oDrv.Path) = 1 Then
'                    DriveMap = Replace(FileName, oDrv.Path, oDrv.sharename)
'                End If

            End If
        Next oDrv

    End If

End Sub
```